Spring Boot 3.0.x to 3.1.x ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint / TestContainers
I am using Spring boot 3, Reactor.io and Postgresql in my project. Before Spring Boot 3.1 everything is okay. I have one integration test which is using Testcontainers of PostgreSQL. But in project after only one change which is 3.0.x (last version) to 3.1.0 test is starting to fail. It is getting "Duplicate key value violates unique constraint". Any point to I can check?

For starters use 3.1.x (the latests in that range and not 3.1.0) then check again.
